# Finitely generated module: terminology.

Tags: group-theory, ring-theory, definition

What's the meaning of the expression: $S$ is a subring of $\mathbb{C}$ finitely generated as $\mathbb{Z}$-module? 
Maybe that the additive group of the ring $S$ is a finitely generated abelian group? Is my answer correct? Thank you very much to everyone for the help!

Comment: Yes, that's correct.